# Role member count only counts roles of the user who sent the command discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to send a list of all of the roles in a server with the member count beside it. It successfully sends the role names but only counts the roles of the user who sent the command. For example, if a user only has `RoleA`, instead of sending `RoleA - 3 RoleB - 5 RoleC - 2`, it will send `RoleA - 1 RoleB - 0 RoleC - 0`.

```js
const roles = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => {    
    return guild.roles.cache.map(role=>role.name).flat().filter(item => item !== '');
});

roles.sort().forEach(roleName => {
    let memberCount = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === roleName).members.size;
    
    if(roleName !== '@everyone')
        roles_as_list += ' ' +roleName+ ' - ' +memberCount+ '\n';
});

msg.channel.send(roles_as_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a fix for your code, but here is a way how to do it much easier:

```js
let roles_as_list = msg.guild.roles.cache.filter(r => r.name !== `@everyone`).sort().map(r => ` ${r.name} - ${r.members.filter(m => !m.user.bot).size}`).join(`\n`);
msg.channel.send(roles_as_list)
```

And just like that, you'll have server roles map that excludes bots from the list